# TableResult hangs when retrieving an existing Azure Table item

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure Tables in order to make CRUD operations with a particular object. I can insert correctly using this code:

```
public async Task CreateOrUpdate(UserCredentials data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        await _cloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        var result = Get(data.RowKey).Result;

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Username = data.Username;
            result.FailedAttempts += 1;

            var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Replace(result);
            await _cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
        }
        else
        {
            data.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            data.FailedAttempts = data.LoginFailed ? 1 : 0;
            TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(data);
            await _cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOperation);
        }
    }
```

First time the item doesn't exist in Azure Tables, but once I have items in the table, the `Get` functionality is not working. It hangs while executing the operation:

```
public async Task<UserCredentials> Get(string key)
    {
        await _cloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        TableOperation retrieve = TableOperation.Retrieve<UserCredentials>(nameof(UserCredentials), key);

        TableResult result = await _cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(retrieve);  <-- It never comes back from here

        return result.Result as UserCredentials;
    }
```

This is my Entity Object:

```
public class UserCredentials : TableEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }
    public int FailedAttempts { get; set; }
    public bool LoginFailed { get; set; }


    public UserCredentials(string username)
    {
        PartitionKey = nameof(UserCredentials);
        RowKey = username;
    }
}
```

So my `await _cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(retrieve);` is never coming back when an existing rowKey is being passed. But it works perfectly if the table is empty (so inserting works fine, but not retrieving from an existing rowKey).

Any idea on why it's not coming back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue.

To fix this, please add a parameter-less constructor for your entity.

```
public class UserCredentials : TableEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }
    public int FailedAttempts { get; set; }
    public bool LoginFailed { get; set; }

    public UserCredentials()
    {

    }

    public UserCredentials(string username)
    {
        PartitionKey = nameof(UserCredentials);
        RowKey = username;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just discovered that 30 sec ago... and yes! that's it. Thanks a lot!